# Using scikit-learn vectorizers and vocabularies with gensim

Tags: python, scikit-learn, topic-modeling, gensim

I am trying to recycle scikit-learn vectorizer objects with gensim topic models. The reasons are simple: first of all, I already have a great deal of vectorized data; second, I prefer the interface and flexibility of scikit-learn vectorizers; third, even though topic modelling with gensim is very fast, computing its dictionaries (`Dictionary()`) is relatively slow in my experience.

Similar questions have been asked before, [especially here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504898/use-sikit-tfidf-with-gensim-lda) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670525/how-do-you-initialize-a-gensim-corpus-variable-with-a-csr-matrix), and the bridging solution is gensim's `Sparse2Corpus()` function which transforms a Scipy sparse matrix into a gensim corpus object.

However, this conversion does not make use of the `vocabulary_` attribute of sklearn vectorizers, which holds the mapping between words and feature ids. This mapping is necessary in order to print the discriminant words for each topic (`id2word` in gensim topic models, described as "a a mapping from word ids (integers) to words (strings)").

I am aware of the fact that gensim's `Dictionary` objects are much more complex (and slower to compute) than scikit's `vect.vocabulary_` (a simple Python `dict`)...

Any ideas to use `vect.vocabulary_` as `id2word` in gensim models?

Some example code:

```
# our data
documents = [u'Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications',
        u'A survey of user opinion of computer system response time',
        u'The EPS user interface management system',
        u'System and human system engineering testing of EPS',
        u'Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement',
        u'The generation of random binary unordered trees',
        u'The intersection graph of paths in trees',
        u'Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering',
        u'Graph minors A survey']

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
# compute vector space with sklearn
vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, ngram_range=(1, 1), max_features=25000)
corpus_vect = vect.fit_transform(documents)
# each doc is a scipy sparse matrix
print vect.vocabulary_
#{u'and': 1, u'minors': 20, u'generation': 9, u'testing': 32, u'iv': 15, u'engineering': 5, u'computer': 4, u'relation': 28, u'human': 11, u'measurement': 19, u'unordered': 37, u'binary': 3, u'abc': 0, u'for': 8, u'ordering': 23, u'graph': 10, u'system': 31, u'machine': 17, u'to': 35, u'quasi': 26, u'time': 34, u'random': 27, u'paths': 24, u'of': 21, u'trees': 36, u'applications': 2, u'management': 18, u'lab': 16, u'interface': 13, u'intersection': 14, u'response': 29, u'perceived': 25, u'in': 12, u'widths': 40, u'well': 39, u'eps': 6, u'survey': 30, u'error': 7, u'opinion': 22, u'the': 33, u'user': 38}

import gensim
# transform sparse matrix into gensim corpus
corpus_vect_gensim = gensim.matutils.Sparse2Corpus(corpus_vect, documents_columns=False)
lsi = gensim.models.LsiModel(corpus_vect_gensim, num_topics=4)
# I instead would like something like this line below
# lsi = gensim.models.LsiModel(corpus_vect_gensim, id2word=vect.vocabulary_, num_topics=2)
print lsi.print_topics(2)
#['0.622*"21" + 0.359*"31" + 0.256*"38" + 0.206*"29" + 0.206*"34" + 0.197*"36" + 0.170*"33" + 0.168*"1" + 0.158*"10" + 0.147*"4"', '0.399*"36" + 0.364*"10" + -0.295*"31" + 0.245*"20" + -0.226*"38" + 0.194*"26" + 0.194*"15" + 0.194*"39" + 0.194*"23" + 0.194*"40"']
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Gensim doesn't require `Dictionary` objects. You can use your plain `dict` as input to `id2word` directly, as long as it maps ids (integers) to words (strings).

In fact anything dict-like will do (including `dict`, `Dictionary`, `SqliteDict`...).

(Btw gensim's `Dictionary` is a simple Python `dict` underneath.
Not sure where your remarks on `Dictionary` performance come from, you can't get a mapping much faster than a plain `dict` in Python. Maybe you're confusing it with text preprocessing (not part of gensim), which can indeed be slow.)

Comment: That was quick and easy, thanks! I tend to get scared by gensim's objects... Didn't occur to me that I just needed to format scikit's `dict`. Shame on me... Regarding the time/performance comments, making the Dictionary in gensim with 1k documents takes me about 0.9 seconds, add another full second to transform them into BoW and Tfidf. In comparison, scikit-learn's TfidfVectorizer does the whole job in 1.2 seconds.

Answer (score 8):

Just to provide with a final example, scikit-learn's vectorizers objects can be transformad into gensim's corpus format with `Sparse2Corpus` while the vocabulary `dict` can be recycled by simply swapping keys and values:

```
# transform sparse matrix into gensim corpus
corpus_vect_gensim = gensim.matutils.Sparse2Corpus(corpus_vect, documents_columns=False)

# transform scikit vocabulary into gensim dictionary
vocabulary_gensim = {}
for key, val in vect.vocabulary_.items():
    vocabulary_gensim[val] = key
```

Comment: or simply `id2word = dict((v, k) for k, v in vect.vocabulary_.iteritems())`

Answer (score 6):

I am also running some code experiments using these two. Apparently there's a way to construct the dictionary from corpus now

```
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
dictionary = Dictionary.from_corpus(corpus_vect_gensim,
                                    id2word=dict((id, word) for word, id in vect.vocabulary_.items()))
```

Then you can use this dictionary for tfidf, LSI or LDA models.

Comment: I replaced the 'vocabulary_gensim' from previous answer with your 'dictionary'. It works for calculating coherence with c_v method from gensim.CoherenceModel() now. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helps (:

Answer (score 3):

The solution in working python 3 code.

```
import gensim
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

def vect2gensim(vectorizer, dtmatrix):
     # transform sparse matrix into gensim corpus and dictionary
    corpus_vect_gensim = gensim.matutils.Sparse2Corpus(dtmatrix, documents_columns=False)
    dictionary = Dictionary.from_corpus(corpus_vect_gensim,
        id2word=dict((id, word) for word, id in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()))

    return (corpus_vect_gensim, dictionary)

documents = [u'Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications',
        u'A survey of user opinion of computer system response time',
        u'The EPS user interface management system',
        u'System and human system engineering testing of EPS',
        u'Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement',
        u'The generation of random binary unordered trees',
        u'The intersection graph of paths in trees',
        u'Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering',
        u'Graph minors A survey']


# compute vector space with sklearn
vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, ngram_range=(1, 1), max_features=25000)
corpus_vect = vect.fit_transform(documents)

# transport to gensim
(gensim_corpus, gensim_dict) = vect2gensim(vect, corpus_vect)
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting up an answer since I do not have a reputation of 50 yet.

Directly using vect.vocabulary_(with keys and values interchanged) will not work on Python 3 since dict.keys() now returns an iterable view and not a list. 
The associated error is:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict_keys") to list
```

To make this work on Python 3, change line 301 in lsimodel.py to

```
self.num_terms = 1 + max([-1] + list(self.id2word.keys()))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Example from the tutorial https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_similarity_queries.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-core-run-similarity-queries-py

with Scikit Tokenizer and Stopwords as the only difference

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
import gensim

from gensim import models


print("Text Similarity with Gensim and Scikit utils")
# compute vector space with sklearn
documents = [
    "Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications",
    "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time",
    "The EPS user interface management system",
    "System and human system engineering testing of EPS",
    "Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement",
    "The generation of random binary unordered trees",
    "The intersection graph of paths in trees",
    "Graph minors IV Widths of trees and well quasi ordering",
    "Graph minors A survey",
]

# Using Scikit learn feature extractor

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, ngram_range=(1, 1), stop_words='english')
corpus_vect = vect.fit_transform(documents)
# take the dict keys out
texts = list(vect.vocabulary_.keys())

from gensim import corpora
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary([texts])

# transform scikit vocabulary into gensim dictionary
corpus_vect_gensim = gensim.matutils.Sparse2Corpus(corpus_vect, documents_columns=False)

# create LSI model
lsi = models.LsiModel(corpus_vect_gensim, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=2)

# convert the query to LSI space
doc = "Human computer interaction"
vec_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(doc.lower().split())
vec_lsi = lsi[vec_bow]  
print(vec_lsi)

# Find similarities
from gensim import similarities
index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(lsi[corpus_vect_gensim])  # transform corpus to LSI space and index it

sims = index[vec_lsi]  # perform a similarity query against the corpus
print(list(enumerate(sims)))  # print (document_number, document_similarity) 2-tuples

sims = sorted(enumerate(sims), key=lambda item: -item[1])
for doc_position, doc_score in sims:
    print(doc_score, documents[doc_position])
```